# Toast achievement animation in android studio

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, toast, android-toast

i was wondering if any one of you knows a way to display this nice looking toast achievement animation(last link of the question), i found a library [Achievement view library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6706) that is close for what i look for but need one feature (set the title and the message gravity). and here another one by [John Persano (super toast)](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts).
if any one could help, pleas , i'm waiting.[this is the toast animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6dWK.gif)

Comment: It seems like "Achievement view library" does exactly what you're looking for. I'm not sure of the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try these libraries, they look lot similar to your needs:

1. https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty
2. https://github.com/Shashank02051997/FancyToast-Android